# ASP.NET WebForms FormsAuthentication problem with cross-domain iFrames

Tags: asp.net, iframe, webforms, forms-authentication, windows-server-2012-r2

Well, I have 2 ASP.NET WebForm websites, running on production on the same windows server machine, let's call them site A and site B. There are some pages in website A in which there is an iFrame, pointing to website B. I want my users to be authenticated on site B when they browse site B through site A (through iFrames). In order to do that, the source of my iFrame on my site A is like that :

```
B.com/index.aspx?guid={aGuid}&pageIWant={pageIWant}
```

So, I will not go into details there because it works and it is not the problem, but how it works basically is that in the **Page_Load** of index.aspx.vb of my site B, I get the guid in the querystrings representing a user, I get this user from database, I log this user using forms authentication and then I redirect the user to the "pageIWant", another querystrings parameter. So, here is what I do in the page_load, basically :

```
/*Get the guid*/
Dim user = /*get user from guid*/
/*some checks*/
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Login, True)
Select Case Request.QueryString("pageIWant")
                            Case "1"
                                Response.Redirect("documents.aspx")
                            Case "2"
                                /*etc*/
                        End Select
```

The index.aspx page of site B does not require authentication, but the page "documents.aspx" does. Hopefully, I did authenticate my user in the page load of index.aspx, so I go through **Application_AuthenticateRequest** in the  **Global.asax.vb** and everything is fine, my user can access the page. Here is the code in my **Application_AuthenticateRequest** method :

```
    Sub Application_AuthenticateRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Request.IsAuthenticated Then
        If Request.Cookies("ESERVICES_LOGIN") IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim aTicket As FormsAuthenticationTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies("ESERVICES_LOGIN").Value)
            HttpContext.Current.User = New GenericPrincipal(New GenericIdentity(aTicket.Name), aTicket.UserData.Split(","c))
        Else
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
            HttpContext.Current.User = New GenericPrincipal(New GenericIdentity(String.Empty, String.Empty), New String() {})
            Response.Clear()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

In this case, when I redirect to the page "documents.aspx", the Request.IsAuthenticated is set to true because I previously called **FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Login, True)**

Here is the problem : since I installed on my windows server machine (hosting the websites) the two following KBs :

1. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4534978/kb4534978
2. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4535104/kb4535104

Request.IsAuthenticated is still **false** when I redirect to "documents.aspx" page, despite the fact that I call FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie before... and no exception is thrown ! My user is not logged in anymore.

I uninstalled the two KB and the problem is not occuring anymore, so I am sure there is something with one of those two KBs that causes my problem.

Something really strange is that when I try to reproduce the problem in localhost, I do not face the problem at all -> the problem seems to happen only when website A and website B do not have the same domain name. I've made multiple tests about this hypothesis and it seems to be true.

So, there is something wrong with the framework (or how I use it), and because of that, FormsAuthentication does not work properly **through iFrame, when the iFrame source does  not have the same domain name as the iFrame container, and when those two  KBs are installed on the windows server machine hosting the website.** That is silly and I cannot  find the problem when debugging.

Please note that in both case, wheter authentication works or not, my auth cookie is created successfully...

Would someone have any idea about what's happening there? Do  not hesitate to ask any questions if my problem is  not clear.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an explanation.

Since 2019, Microsoft is releasing KBs that changes the default value of the "SameSite" attribute for the cookies. Before, when creating an auth cookie with FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie, the SameSite attribute was not specified, and in most browsers, the default value for it was "none" and it worked just fine. (this is not the case with Chrome anymore since february 2020, the default value became "lax").

Now, with the  KBs I mentionned, the default value became "Strict", that's why my authentication doesn't work anymore in my case.

So, I'll have to specify the  samesite attribute of my auth cookie to "None" manually if possible, and think about the security issues I could have with that. As a last resort, I could also just use the same domain  name for my two websites.